# Sinon's spy.threw() does not behave as expected when passing it an error argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I'm writing simple unit tests with sinon.JS. The code under test has some type checking, which throws a TypeError:

```
Tx = class Tx {
    constructor(date) {
        if (!(date instanceof Date)) throw new TypeError();
        this.date = date;
    }
 }
```

In my test.js, I'm using sinon to test that the Tx instantiation fails when the argument is not a Date:

```
describe('Tx', function() {
    describe('#constructor', function() {
        it('should fail when not passed a date as 1st param', function() {
            var txSpy = sinon.spy(Tx.constructor);
            try {
                tx = new Tx(true);
            } catch (e) {
                // test success
                console.log('Error: '+e)
            }
        }
    }
}
result = txSpy.threw(new TypeError());
assert(result);
```

The assertion fails, even though the catch output is "Error: TypeError"; The same result occurs when passing a String description of the error type (i.e. "TypeError", as per [the sinon API](http://unexpected.js.org/unexpected-sinon/assertions/spy/threw/)).

Any hints? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The `TypeError` instance you expect is not the one which got thrown, although they are instances of the same class.

In the documentation you linked, you will notice that when the `.threw()` method is called with an `error` object parameter (and returns success), the `error` object is the one which got thrown, not another instance of the same class.

To check for the class of exception used, it looks like you should provide a `{ name : "ExceptionClassName" }` (i.e. `{ name: "TypeError" }` in your case) parameter.

Comment: I thought this might be the case... but then how would I check for type-equality rather than instance-equality?

Comment: @Navonod I've edited in what looks like the best way, but you should know that I've never used `sinon`. While I think my answer should solve your immediate problem, it might fail for some corner cases or simply not be best-practice.